# How do I update unlockable characters in SpriteKit game with Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift3, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, skspritenode

I have currently made a game featuring one player. I also made a character screen where the user can choose which character he/she wants to play with. How do I make it so that a certain high score unlocks a certain character, and allows the user to equip this character to use in the game?

Right now my player has his own swift file that defines all the properties of him:

```
import SpriteKit
class Player: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite {
var initialSize = CGSize(width:150, height: 90)
var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Rupert")

let maxFlyingForce: CGFloat = 80000
let maxHeight: CGFloat = 900
var health:Int = 1
var invulnerable = false
var damaged = false
var damageAnimation = SKAction()
var dieAnimation = SKAction()
var forwardVelocity: CGFloat = 190
var powerAnimation = SKAction()



init() {
super.init(texture:nil, color: .clear, size: initialSize)
createAnimations()
self.run(soarAnimation, withKey: "soarAnimation")
let bodyTexture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug3")
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bodyTexture, size: self.size)
self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.9
self.physicsBody?.mass = 10
self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.rupert.rawValue
self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.treat.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.winky.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue


func createAnimations() {
let rotateUpAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0.75, duration: 0.475)
rotateUpAction.timingMode = .easeOut
let rotateDownAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0, duration: 0.475)
rotateDownAction.timingMode = .easeIn
let flyFrames: [SKTexture] = [
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug1"),
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug2"),
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug3"),
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug4"),
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug3"),
textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug2")
    ]
let flyAction = SKAction.animate(with:flyFrames, timePerFrame: 0.07)
flyAnimation = SKAction.group([SKAction.repeatForever(flyAction), rotateUpAction])
let soarFrames:[SKTexture] = [textureAtlas.textureNamed("pug5")]
let soarAction = SKAction.animate(with: soarFrames, timePerFrame: 1)
soarAnimation = SKAction.group([SKAction.repeatForever(soarAction), rotateDownAction])
```

This is not all the code but you get the point.

I then say: `let player = Player()` in my Gamescene file which essentially attaches all the attributes in the player file to my player that will be seen in the Gamescene. Even if I am able to replace the initial player with a certain different player, there are so many animations that I don't know how to replace everything at once. I want to set a condition that spans over both the gamescene class and the player class so that it can just sub out certain images for other ones and keep the same actions.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some techniques you can use for making things like this more manageable:

- Have a naming convention for your character images and/or sprite sheets, so that you can pass in a name to your Player() constructor.  Then, instead of loading texturenamed("pug3"), you load up texturenamed("\(playerName)3").  If the only difference between your characters are the sprite sheets, this is actually all you need on the Player end.
- If your characters are more complex, with differences beyond just the images, like being larger or having more health, then you will probably want to go with a more data-oriented approach.  There are a couple of approaches to this, but a handy one is to read your texture names, hitbox sizes, health levels, etc., out of a .plist file instead of hard-coding them.  Then just pass in the name of the .plist file to load for the character you want.  Then, to create a new character, you just create a new .plist file.  Another approach would be to create a "character definition" struct that you could pass to the Player constructor that contains the information you need to construct the player (this, in turn, could be loaded from a .plist file, as well, but you could also hard-code them or save them directly using codable serialization).
- If neither of the above approaches are sufficient, say if you need different behavior between characters, you could always go the subclassing route - pull the various parts and pieces out into functions, and then override those functions to add the specific functionality you need for more complex characters.